# set a BASH variable equal to the output from 'top' command?

Tags: bash

I know how to set a BASH variable equal to the output from a command, but it doesn't work in case of 'top' command for me, see below

```
cat aTOPFWK.sh
OUTPUT = $(top -b -n 1 | egrep 'fwk3' |  awk '{print $9}')
echo "${OUTPUT}"
./aTOPFWK.sh: line 3: OUTPUT: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

get rid of the blanks around the "=":

```
OUTPUT=$(top -b -n 1 | egrep 'fwk3' |  awk '{print $9}')
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```